# How to filter a nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in which i am trying to filter based on a give condition. The array contains objects with `company` and `products` fields.

The filter term is `productType: "Timespot"`.

I would like to get the company and its products which only has the `productType: "Timespot"`

```
const dummyData = [
  {
    companyName: "Company A",
    products: [
      {
        productType: "Variabel pris",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    companyName: "Company B",
    products: [
      {
        productType: "Fastpris",
      },
      {
        productType: "Fastpris",
      },
      {
        productType: "Fastpris",
      },
      {
        productType: "Timespot",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    companyName: "Company C",
    products: [
      {
        productType: "Spotpris",
      },
      {
        productType: "Timespot",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

```
const expectedResult = [
  {
    companyName: "Company B",
    products: [
      {
        productType: "Timespot",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    companyName: "Company C",
    products: [
      {
        productType: "Timespot",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

What i am trying:

```
  dummyData.filter(({ products }) => {
     products.some(product => product.productType === "Timespot")
  });
```

To provide more context is that i want to get the company and its product which match the given condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem with your approach is that the filter function will only filter the first array and not the nested one, in order to do what you desire I would use a `reduce()`

e.g

```js
dummyData.reduce((acc,cur)=> { 
    const filteredProducts = cur.products.filter((p)=> p.productType === "Timespot")

    if(filteredProducts.length){
        acc.push({...cur, products:filteredProducts})    
    }
    
    return acc

}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
function filterProductType(arr, prodType) {
  return arr.filter(obj => obj.products.some(type => type.productType === prodType));
}

console.log(filterProductType(dummyData, "Timespot"));
```

Returns:

```
0: companyName: "Company B"
products: Array(4)
  0: {productType: 'Fastpris'}
  1: {productType: 'Fastpris'}
  2: {productType: 'Fastpris'}
  3: {productType: 'Timespot'}
length: 4

1: companyName: "Company C"
products: Array(2)
  0: {productType: 'Spotpris'}
  1: {productType: 'Timespot'}
length: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.filter` on the main array, combined with `array.find` on the nested array of products.

```js
const dummyData=[{companyName:"Company A",products:[{productType:"Variabel pris"}]},{companyName:"Company B",products:[{productType:"Fastpris"},{productType:"Fastpris"},{productType:"Fastpris"},{productType:"Timespot"}]},{companyName:"Company C",products:[{productType:"Spotpris"},{productType:"Timespot"}]}];

const filtered = dummyData.filter(({products}) => {
  return products.find(({productType}) => productType === 'Timespot');
})

console.log(filtered)
```

If you find that you also need to filter by some other `productType` elsewhere, you could make a more generic function to handle this.

```js
const dummyData=[{companyName:"Company A",products:[{productType:"Variabel pris"}]},{companyName:"Company B",products:[{productType:"Fastpris"},{productType:"Fastpris"},{productType:"Fastpris"},{productType:"Timespot"}]},{companyName:"Company C",products:[{productType:"Spotpris"},{productType:"Timespot"}]}];

const companyByProductType = ({data, type}) => {
  return data.filter(({products}) => {
    return products.find(({productType}) => productType === type);
  })
}

console.log(companyByProductType({data: dummyData, type: 'Timespot'}))
```